# FindPrivateKey Location in VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, wcf, installation

Where can one find FindPrivateKey.exe after a fresh VS2008 install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding to the [WCF forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/72f46406-d85c-4f06-9cbe-7733075bfdbc) it is a sample app.

Comment: For those interested, here's a working link to the .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 sample app:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=ed9c315c-31ac-4ccb-b62b-721af1e2bfa8&displaylang=en